# IE11 javascript redirection history issue

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser-history, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way in IE11 to redirect through JavaScript from `pageA` to `pageB`, and `pageA` to remain in history?

If I have in `pageA` code like this:

```
this.location = "pageB.htm";
```

In any IE 8/9/10 it redirects to `pageB.htm`, and `pageA.htm` remains in history.

I can go back to it with the back button, with history.go(-1) etc.

In IE11 however, `pageA.htm` does not remain in history.

I have tried all the ways that I know: `window.location`, `window.location.href`, `document.location`, etc... etc...

None of them keeps the redirecting page in history.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried `history.pushState({}, 'Title', 'pageB.htm')` ? - it won't work <IE10, however if it turns out to work well in IE11, you can later polyfill it: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: Does this also happen if you use `window.location.href='pageB.htm';` or `window.location.assign('pageB.htm');`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. `history.pushState` seemed promising, but has a strange behavior in IE11 and Opera. If in pageA.htm I put  `history.pushState({}, '', location.href);  window.location.href='pageB.htm';`   and then from pageB.htm do `history.go(-1)`  ,the address bar of IE11 shows the URL of pageA.htm, but the browser doesn't actually go pageA.htm, it remains on pageB. In Opera, the URL in the address bar also changes, but it displays a blank page (neither pageA nor pageB)  In Firefox and Chrome all works very well.  Other suggestions don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the window.open function a try
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```
window.open('pageB.html','_self', null , false)
```